# Doing minor version update of Ceph cluster with ceph-ansible and rolling-update playbook

Tags: ansible, ceph

I want to upgrade my ceph cluster to the latest minor version of the current installed major version (mimic). I have a ceph-ansible setup for deployment which is used to deploy new nodes with the `site.yml` playbook. I learned from the documentation that I need to execute the rolling-update playbook in order to perform an update be it minor or major.

For a minor update I just execute the playbook with keeping `ceph_stable_release` set to my current installed version.

To do a major update (after doing the minor update) I change `ceph_stable_release` in my case from mimic to nautilus and then execute the rolling-update playbook.

The [documentation](https://docs.ceph.com/projects/ceph-ansible/en/latest/day-2/upgrade.html) is short on this information.

Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

I checked with the [ceph community user mailing list](https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/) and was assured that my assumption is correct.

To do a minor update of your ceph cluster keep the variable ceph_stable_release at your current installed version.

To check what versions your ceph components are currently running you can issue these commands, if you want to reassure yourself:

```
# ceph tell mon.* version 

and

# ceph tell osd.* version
```

The output should show same versions for monitors and osds.

Running the upgrade with

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory infrastructure-playbooks/rolling_update.yml
```

Will first update all monitors, then managers followed by osds. Depending on your ceph setup other types of services will be updated as well. Since I only run monitors, osds and managers I can't tell in which order these will occur.

For me updating mimic to its latests version, I had only one hiccup. ceph-ansible was waiting for an updated osd to recover, but one PG stayed in `active+undersized+remapped+backfilling`. It did not recover until I removed the `norebalance` flag with

```
# ceph osd unset norebalance
```

After this the osd recovered immediately and ceph-ansible could continue. Just as a side note, if this should happen to you as well.